# why paypal developer instructions on c# is different on github?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, paypal

on the paypal website  it says this :

> .NET SDK
>
> Prerequisites
>
> Visual Studio 2008 or higher log4net 1.2.10 NuGet 2.2 All C# request
>   samples use and are dependent on the .NET SDK.
>
> To install the C# SDK as a dependency in your project, please run the
>   following nuget command.
>
> nuget install PayPalRestApiSDK -version 0.5.0 Source and documentation
>   at: github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-dotnet

source : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/  ( chose the C# one )
although the nugget command is wrong, its

> install-package

and not

> nuget install

i got confused because i don't know which instructions to follow the ones on the `github` link that is provided or the on from the paypal website 
github instructions

> 1. Download the Dependencies
>
> To begin using this SDK, first download this SDK from NuGet.
>
> NuGet Install -Package PayPal
>
> Optionally, also download log4net to give your application enhanced
>   logging capabilities.
>
> NuGet Install -Package log4net

on the paypal web it says to install PayPalRestApiSDK & on the github web it says to install the PayPal package and i dont know which one is the truth,

Comment: Did you try them? I've never seen `Nuget Install` used, only `Install-Package`.

Comment: ^, and in addition - almost every API you're gonna work with will be frustrating at the beginning (technically, not logically). Be thankful if this is all the problems you will face.

Comment: yeah i tried them and they doesn't work the command is Install-Package,but my problem isn't this

Comment: I would ignore both instructions and simply use the NuGet Manager to search online for the term "paypal", see what comes up and play around.

Answer (score 2):

This is Jason, the developer for the [PayPal .NET SDK](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-net-sdk) on GitHub.

`NuGet Install -Package PayPal` is for installing the package via the **Windows Command-Line** using the **[NuGet Command-Line Utility](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)**.

`Install-Package PayPal` is for installing the package via the **NuGet Package Manager Console**.

The instructions on GitHub are correct, but they're missing the clarification that it's for the Windows Command-Line - [I've since updated this to be clearer](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK#1-download-the-dependencies).  I'll also work on making this part of the README clearer with the next SDK release.

---

Regarding the documentation on PayPal Developer, the documentation team is currently working on removing that outdated SDK documentation. It should hopefully happen sometime shortly after the winter holiday break.  The PayPal SDK team is currently working with the documentation team to provide a much better hub of SDK-specific documentation on PayPal Developer.

---

Regarding the [**PayPal**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal) and [**RestApiSdk**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/restapisdk) NuGet packages, the correct package to use is **PayPal**.

The **RestApiSdk** package is the older version that had a dependency on the **PayPalCoreSdk** package, which is also used by all the Classic SDKs.  Because the REST SDK is what PayPal will be supporting with new features moving forward, it made sense to break away from the Classic SDKs and integrate the Core SDK into the REST SDK.  To make this clearer for developers of which library they should use, the package name was simplified to just "PayPal".  The descriptions for each SDK on NuGet should make it clear which one you should use.  If it's not clear enough, please let me know what needs to be added, and I'd be more than happy to make the change. :)

Once the **PayPal** package becomes feature-complete, I will be making an update of **RestApiSdk** that puts a dependency on the newer **PayPal** package to help developers make the transition (as well as marking the package as hidden on NuGet).

Comment: Well one can't ask for a better answer than that.